# Рендер блока в зависимости от открытого представления

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, view, razor

Как можно реализовать рендер секции кода внутри view таким образом, что бы по умолчнию рендерился какой то общий кусок html кода, а в случае открытия определенной view'шки общий код заменялся на что то другое? Сейчас в общем DesignLayout.cshtml есть тег , он рендерится на всех страницах, но в areas, в представлении service необходимо что бы код изменился на следующий (). Пока вижу очевидное решение, в виде наблюдения за тем какая вьюха открыта, но хочется верить что есть более элегантное решение.

Answer (score 0):

а что если во view service не прописывать, что у этого view Layout = DesignLayout.cshtml? т.е. просто не подключать этот layout в это view?

Answer (score 0):

Просто присвойте данной странице другую мастер-страницу "AnotherDesignLayout.cshtml"

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AnotherDesignLayout.cshtml";
}
```